# Regex for 11, 12 etc but not 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a data set, and only keep Scenarios 11, 12, 13, 14 etc (but not Scenario 1).

My input looks like this:

```
structure(list(Title.1 = structure(c(1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Scenario 1", 
"Scenario 10", "Scenario 11", "Scenario 12", "Scenario 13", "Scenario 14", 
"Scenario 2", "Scenario 3", "Scenario 4", "Scenario 5", "Scenario 6", 
"Scenario 7", "Scenario 8", "Scenario 9"), class = "factor"), 
    Color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Blue", "Red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

and my output would ideally look like this:

```
structure(list(Title.1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Scenario 10", "Scenario 11", 
"Scenario 12", "Scenario 13", "Scenario 14"), class = "factor"), 
    Color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Blue"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

I could define what I'm keeping (ie. keep = c('Scenario 11', 'Scenario 12' etc) and then filter it by  "Title" and then filter it again by 'Color', but I'm sure I could do it in one line with a Regex.

My issue is that I can't seem to tell it to ignore Scenario 1.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with regex we can use `grepl` to select rows which have "1" followed by another digit along with `Color = 'Blue'`.

```
subset(df, grepl('\\b1\\d\\b', Title.1) & Color == 'Blue')

#       Title.1 Color
#24 Scenario 10  Blue
#25 Scenario 11  Blue
#26 Scenario 12  Blue
#27 Scenario 13  Blue
#28 Scenario 14  Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter` with `str_detect` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(Title.1, '\\b1\\d\\b') & Color == 'Blue')
```